# Filter by string in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models: UserProfile and User_Details and I want to display the details for one user.I think the problem is at the filter and I don't know how to filter after a string,I'm new to django.How can I fix this?

```
class ShowProfile(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'profile.html'


    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        details=User_Details.objects.all().filter(user=request.user.username)
        serializer = ProfileSerializer2(details, many=True)
        pprint.pprint(json.loads(JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)))
        return Response({'fields ': serializer})

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = CreatePostSerializer(data=request.data)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response({'fields': serializer })

        user = UserProfile.objects.filter(username=request.user.username).first()
        serializer.save(user=user)
        pprint.pprint(json.loads(JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)))
        return redirect('mainPage')
```

Models:

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    pass


class User_Details(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank = True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True, default='')
    public_info=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
```

Template:

```
{% extends 'base2.html' %}
{% load rest_framework %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
             <div class="list-group ">
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active">Profile</a>
              <a href="{% url 'show_my_posts'  pk=user.id %}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">My Posts</a>
         </div>
</div>
{% for d in fields %}
  {{d.firs_name }}<h1>a</h1>
{% endfor %}


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Which string are you referring to ?

Comment: `details=User_Details.objects.all().filter(user=request.user.username)` request.user.username returns a name,but I think the problem is when it wants to compare it with 'user'

Comment: `details=User_Details.objects.filter(user=request.user)` ?

Comment: No :( . This is what is displayed  : ' [ ] '

Comment: Alex why are you comparing `user` with `username`, what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I have a 'UserProfile' with 'username':admin and 'password': 1234. For this user I made some details:'first_name', 'last_name','gender','public_info' (User_Details model) and now I want to display the 'admin' info into a template.I edit my post with the template.

Comment: Did you check your data with `RetrieveAPIView` ?

Comment: Is your `request.user` a `UserProfile` or a `User`?